# Certificate problem with yast2

Tags: curl, repository, ssl-certificate, opensuse

Out of stupidity I removed using yast the package "ssl-cert". At this point yast2 started throwing the error:

> Download failed: 
>   Download (curl) error for 'https://nu.novell.com/repo/repoindex.xml?cookies=0&credentials=NCCcredentials':
>   Error code: Unrecognized error
>   Error message: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: 
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

And of course a redownload and install of ssl-cert is not possible,I get the same error
So I tried downloading and installing the openssl package by hand, but still I got nowhere
Does anyone knows how to reinstall this ssl-cert package again??

Thanks and best regards,
Moataz

Comment: This seems [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 1):

Seeing nu.novell.com suggests that you're on SLES, not openSUSE. Anyway, getting the certificate rpm from openSUSE should do it:

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/11.2/repo/oss/suse/noarch/openssl-certs-0.9.8h-28.1.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uhv openssl-certs*rpm
```

Afterwards you can use yast2 to install the exact version corresponding to SLES.